# How to sort multiple colums by levels on a custom order

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, excel-interop

I need to sort the columns A, B, and C, with A being the first in the priority list, then B, and finally C. Each of these columns has its own custom order.

I tried sorting it with Interop, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to use the Sort and SortSpecial when I try to run the Sort methid I get this error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '_Sort method of Range class failed'" in the first sort and when I try to do SortSpecial I just get a compile Error.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Text;
using AppExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AppExcel.Application excelApp = new AppExcel.Application();

        AppExcel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Path\To\The\File.xlsx");

        AppExcel.Worksheet worksheet = (AppExcel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];

        AppExcel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;


        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        foreach (AppExcel.Range mergedCell in worksheet.UsedRange.Cells)
        {
            if (mergedCell.MergeCells)
            {
                mergedCell.UnMerge();
            }
        }

        // Define the ranges that we want to sort
        AppExcel.Range rangeColumnA = range.Columns["A"];
        AppExcel.Range rangeColumnB = range.Columns["B"];
        AppExcel.Range rangeColumnC = range.Columns["C"];

        // Define the custom orders
        string[] customOrderColumnA = { "CPU", "GPU", "Mother Board", "RAM" };
        string[] customOrderColumnB = { "Asus", "MSI", "Gibabyte", "Zotac" };
        string[] customOrderColumnC = { "In Stock", "Out of Stock" };
        // Ajusta los custom orders según tus necesidades

        // Sort by the custom order
        range.Sort(rangeColumnA, AppExcel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                   Header: AppExcel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Orientation: AppExcel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
                   OrderCustom: string.Join(",", customOrderColumnA));

        range.Sort(rangeColumnB, AppExcel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
                   Header: AppExcel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Orientation: AppExcel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
                   OrderCustom: string.Join(",", customOrderColumnB));

        range.Sort(rangeColumnC, AppExcel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
              Header: AppExcel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Orientation: AppExcel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
              OrderCustom: string.Join(",", customOrderColumnC));

        // Save and close the Excel file
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close();

        // Close the Excel application
        excelApp.Quit();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Record a macro and see what it does, then just copy that.